Как увеличить дальность прорисовки теней и повысить их контрастность в Unity?
Из-за того, что моя карта в Unity большая, тени начинают прорисовываться на определённом расстоянии, которое нужно изменить на большее значение. Также тени кажутся не такими тёмными, как бы мне хотелось.
Моя версия Unity 2022.3.20f1.

